# How to keep sticky notes from falling down?

Tags: office-supplies, adhesive

I love sticky notes. I have them on my wall, on my desk, on my face, etc. However, if a breeze occurs or time passes, they fall down. I've tried using a piece of clear tape, which works, but is inconvenient. What can I do (without using tape or harming the surface on which I stick them) to keep them from falling down?

Comment: Good question.  I haven't found any solution other than removable tape. (Which is why this is a comment.) :-)

Comment: Replace them after unsticking them a few times? ....they don't last so long when you unstick them and restick them a number of times.

Comment: None of your reasons make sense people or nor do they work. Please think of something that well help because i really need help with my sticky notes. Pleaseeeee!!!!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your notes are probably falling down because you separate the note you need from another note incorrectly, i.e. by pulling from the end of sticky note. Therefore sticky edge bends and the note pulls itself from the surface you stuck it to.

Instead try separating it from another by pulling it off from the right or left, and try not to bend it.

To elucidate this refer to the following visual:

> [image]
>
> [original image](http://blog.apastyle.org/.a/6a01157041f4e3970b019102b91876970c-pi)

Comment: That can't be it, because I peel mine from the side and I have the same problem.

Comment: @starsplusplus, if you're taking the sticky note off the pad correctly, then it is likely due to a dirty/dusty surface. Make sure you clean the area you plan to put the note prior to affixing it.

Comment: I think they're just not sticky enough to remain stuck to vertical surfaces. If I trim the non-sticky part (making them lighter) they last a bit longer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some tips:

- Never touch the sticky portion. This wears away at the sticky material and can make it less prone to sticking.
- Clean the area you want to adhere it to. If the area you adhere it to is all dirty the note won't adhere properly.

Here are some methods to make them stick:

- Use glue. If you use a glue stick that is water soluble that should make it stick to objects and not leave a mark.
- Take a piece of tape and fold it over so that it is double sided and use that. This method may leave a mark depending on the tape.

  ---

[Invest in stickier sticky notes, possibly.](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/which-sticky-note-is-the-stickiest)

Check out [LifeHacker. com](http://lifehacker.com/331425/restickable-glue-stick-makes-sticky-notes)

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe that nobody has posted this yet...

First, one thing I've been told is to not pull sticky notes upwards or sideways. Doing so causes them to bend, which allows grime to get between the sticky surface and whatever surface it's attached to. That obviously reduces its ability to stick to a surface.

Instead, prepare the note (write or draw whatever you want on it) first, then **lift it slightly from the bottom (the edge opposite to the sticky edge), *place a finger underneath it to hold the remaining ones in place, and pull straight toward you*.** Place it flat against the surface you want it to adhere to (after cleaning the surface, if necessary), and gently flatten it against the surface.

If that is not sufficient, while this latter is admittedly not a life hack, you should consider purchasing "super-sticky" sticky notes.

Comment: Thanks, only your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all the methods mentioned above, wiping the surface you are sticking your notes on may increase the time the note stays there